# Reverse for ' sign-in' not found. ' sign-in' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

I have urls.py in project.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path("", include("core.urls")),
path("user/", include("userauths.urls"))
> ]

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then, I create an app named "userauths". In my app I have userauths/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from userauths import views as auth_views

app_name = "userauths"

urlpatterns = [
    path("sign-up/", auth_views.register_view, name="sign-up"),
    path("sign-in/", auth_views.login_view, name="sign-in"),
    path("sign-out/", auth_views.logout_view, name="sign-out"),
]
```

In index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="{% url 'userauths: sign-in' %}">Sign-in</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> But when runserver django, it display errors. I don't know this url Sign-in how to wrong?
> `Reverse for ' sign-in' not found. ' sign-in' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: `Reverse for ' sign-in' not found.` See that space before `sign-in`?  That's the reason.  Edit the html template and change `'userauths: sign-in'` to `'userauths:sign-in'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is the space between **:** and **sign-in**, in the message, it says `' sign-in' not found` with the space; try to remove it.

Another option, check the current URLs with [django-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/), you can add this dependency and exec `./manage.py show_urls` and see all the URLs with the name to copy directly.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is ' sign-in'. I fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer is correct please check it to show that this question is resolved